# LinkedIn Ingtegration in Android

Tags: android, linkedin-api

I am making a demo project where integrating linkedin. In the developer site of linked in added hashkey and package but still getting **{
  "errorCode": "INVALID_REQUEST",
  "errorMessage": "either bundle id or package name / hash are invalid, unknown, malformed"
}**

Please note:i have seen many  blog and question in the stackoverflow but still unable to resolve. and yes m entering correct package name and hash key.

Answer (score 2):

1. If you have [Generated a debug key hash value](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk).
2. If you've added all you package hashes correctly in your LinkedIn Developer Console.
3. And finally you might want to save changes by clicking the blue button labelled "Update".

Test your app again

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely your hash key, try generating it using the below code.

Try this code in your MainActivity

```
try {
    PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("Package name",
            PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
    for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
        Log.e("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
    }
} catch(PackageManager.NameNotFoundException| NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
}
```